# ¿Como utilizar este token para validar el inicio de session, AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, jwt

Actualmente tengo controlado el inicio de sesion con un WebService en laravel utilizando la siguiente libreria: JWTAuth

Aca el metodo en laravel:

```
public function userAuth(Request $request)
{

    $usuario        = $request->input('usuario');
    $password       = $request->input('password');
    $token          = null;

    try 
    {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt(['usuario' => $usuario, 'password' => $password])) 
        {
            $this->records  = Array();
            $this->message  = 'Datos incorrectos';
            $this->result   = false;
            $statusCode     = 200;

                $response = [
                    'message'   => $this->message,
                    'result'    => $this->result,
                    'records'   => $this->records,
                ];
            return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->records = Auth::user();
            $this->message = 'Autenticado exitosamente';
            $this->result  = true;
            $statusCode    = 200;

                $response = [
                    'message'   => $this->message,
                    'result'    => $this->result,
                    'records'   => $this->records,
                ];
            return response()->json($response, $statusCode,compact('token'));
        }

    } 
    catch (JWTException $ex) 
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'somthing_went_wrong'], 500);    
    }
}
```

Si los parametros usuario y contraseña son correctos asignara un token:

```
{"message": "Autenticado exitosamente","result": true,"records": {
"id": 1,
"usuario": "admin",
"nombre": "Administrador",
"email": "admin@gmail.com",
"idtipousuario": 1,
"telefono": 54203090,
"estado": 1,
"created_at": "2017-02-13 18:34:01",
"updated_at": "2017-02-13 18:34:01"}}
```

El WebService lo testeo en postman y el token lo devuelve correctamente en el encabezado (Headers)

```
token →eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDhcL3Npc3RlbWFlcnBcL3B1YmxpY1wvd3NcL2xvZ2luSldUIiwiaWF0IjoxNDkxNzE1OTQwLCJleHAiOjE0OTE3MTk1NDAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MTcxNTk0MCwianRpIjoiMDJkNDYwZWMxM2M1YjE5NDhjNjBmNzYxYWFmYTlmYzUifQ.lpAclBBP6QjH7b8E9ZnyQ09jrqVc4sS3gvo4LK0daAU
```

Con Angularjs en el archivo app.state.js
tengo el siguiente codigo donde controlo las vistas publicas y privadas de tal manera que en el navegador si la persona no esta logueada con su token no podra acceder a ninguna vista mas que al login:

```
.run(['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope){              
                    var token = 'token'; //Viene el Token
                    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    if (toState.module === 'private' && !token) {
                        console.log("Debe iniciar sesion");
                        $state.go('login');
                        e.preventDefault();
                    } else if (toState.module === 'public' && token) {
                        console.log("Contenido mostrado con credenciales correctas y token");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $state.go('restricted.dashboard');
                    };
                });
            }
]);
```

El problema es que no se de que manera puedo utilizar el token que viene en el WebService de la funcion `run([])` y asi acceder a las rutas privadas si viene el token.

Comment: Buenas, estás usando angular-jwt? Esto te puede ayudar: https://auth0.com/blog/handling-jwts-on-angular-is-finally-easier/

Comment: perdon de lado de angular utilizo, Satellizer.